# Can mutiple OR conditions be put inside a CASE function?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I think this means consider the first case or second case or so on.If any one of them is true, return 1. Am I right?

```
case when upper(casetype) = 'ADHOC_SUCCESSFUL' 
       then 1 
     when casetype like 'Boundary_Issue_T%' 
       then 1 
     when upper(casetype) like '%ACTIVE_SUC%' 
       then 1 
End as Successful
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` expression guarantees that the conditions are evaluated in order.  The expression returns the `then` clause associated with the first `when` that evaluates to true.

In this case, you could write this as:

```
(case when upper(casetype) = 'ADHOC_SUCCESSFUL' or
           casetype like 'Boundary_Issue_T%' or
           upper(casetype) like '%ACTIVE_SUC%' 
      then 1 
 end) as Successful
```

I would also be inclined to add `else 0`, so the result is either `0` or `1`, rather than `NULL` or `1`.

Redshift supports boolean types, so you can also do:

```
(upper(casetype) = 'ADHOC_SUCCESSFUL' or
 casetype like 'Boundary_Issue_T%' or
 upper(casetype) like '%ACTIVE_SUC%' 
) as Successful
```